# How to put file from selected directory in arraylist Android studio

Tags: java, android

Good day. I have a problem like this: i have DialogBrowser which open fileBrowser and i want to get all files with .mp3 form selected directory to my ArrayList mySongs. But i don`t understand how do it. This is mp3 player and next my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
String[] items;
FetchSongs fs;
ArrayList<File> mySongs;
ProgressDialog dialog;
ImageView browser;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    browser = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.browser);

    fs=new FetchSongs();
    dialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Подождите пожалуйста, идет загрузка песен...");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();

    //Если песни не загружены или не найдены:
    while(fs.getfetchstatus()!=true){
        mySongs=fs.findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    }
    if(mySongs!=null){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    mySongs = fs.getsonglist();

     //Инициализируем наш массив куда поместим все песни для ЛистВью
    items= new String[mySongs.size()];
    for (int i=0;i<mySongs.size();i++){
        items[i]=mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp3","");
    }
    //Назначаем адаптер для ЛистВью с массивом из найденных песен, и передаем их все на следующий активити
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
    lv.setAdapter(adp);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Player.class);
            intent.putExtra("pos",i);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

public void onClickBtn (View v) {

    File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "//DIR//");
    FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(this, mPath);
    fileDialog.setFileEndsWith(new String[]{".mp3"}); // здесь в массив желаемые типы файлов.

    // а это выбор папки
   fileDialog.addDirectoryListener(new FileDialog.DirectorySelectedListener() {
       @Override
       public void directorySelected(File directory) {


       }
   });

       fileDialog.setSelectDirectoryOption(false);
       fileDialog.showDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `listFiles(FILE_FILTER)` inside a for loop function on the selected directory object where FILE_FILTER is a `FilenameFilter` object. In your case create a filter which will check if the extension is ".mp3". Then add each of the file to a `ArrayList`.

Comment: Could you typing of example?